# The holy trinity of Exchange, Sharepoint, and.... Macs :(

Tags: exchange, sharepoint, mac

We have some Public Folders containing Calendars, that were originally set up using Kerio. We've since migrated to Exchange (2010 SP1), and are in the process of recreating some of the systems we had in place. For the most part, we're flexible, and aren't tied to any one system, but would like to have things tied together nicely.

The mail migration is going smoothly, but Macs can't tie into Public Folder Calendars because microsoft insists on using ASPX pages instead of iCal style calendars. We've successfully gotten Sharepoint Calendars made that (with the help of MashPoint) can be viewed as read-only on Macs and iPhones, but it's a lame "solution".

We would prefer to use just Exchange, as we intend to do room booking thru the "Room Mailbox" system that Exchange supports (of which a skeletal system is in place that works for the most part).

Sharepoint can't just glom data from an Exchange calendar natively, you have to jump through hoops and export ICSes, and then import them into Sharepoint. It isn't live. You need to roll over to Sharepoint, and then use that from then on, which would abandon our scheduling system, or have two sets of different calendars...

Does anyone have a good system for dealing with this? We can't be the only campus using Macs on desks with Exchange (and/or Sharepoint) on the backend.

Comment: What version of SharePoint